# XSD - How can I describe a complexType whose children and 1 or more of any element

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am trying to create and element description which will contain XHTML. I do not know at design time what the contents will be. What I want do do is something like this:

```
 <xs:element name="section" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:any minOccurs="0"></xs:any>
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

"section" will contain 1..* other elements. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a an XSD N00b. If you do not describe the contents of the xs:element they are not processed.

```
 <xs:element name="section" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

Doh!